# Copying first half of dynamic array into second half failed in C?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, allocation

I wanted to copy the first half of my dynamic array into the second half of the same array, but the output here is from ptr[100] to ptr[200] 9.90. I think I coded everything fine but I dont know where the problme is. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    int j;
    
    double * ptr = calloc(100, sizeof(double));
    
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return 0;

        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ptr [i] = i / 10.0;
        }
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("ptr[%d] = %.2f\n", i, ptr[i]);
        
        }
        
        if (realloc(ptr, 200) == NULL)
            return 0;


            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
                for (j = 100; j < 201; j++) 
                    ptr [j] = ptr[i];
                
        
            
            
            for (j = 100; j < 201; j++) 
                    printf("ptr[%d] = %.2f\n", j, ptr[j]);
        
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `realloc(ptr, 200)` should be `realloc(ptr, 200 * sizeof *ptr)`

Comment: I tried it out. It isnt working

Answer (score 0):

You are underallocating on the realloc.  You didn't make enough space for 200 doubles, so attempting to access `ptr[x]` is undefined behavior for values of x > 99.  Also, `realloc` may move the memory, so you need to assign the new value back to `ptr`. For example:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, 200 * sizeof *ptr);
if( ptr == NULL ){
    perror("realloc");
    exit(1);
}
```

And after this, accessing `ptr[200]` is undefined behavior.  You need to reduce the scope of the loop index to `for( j = 100; j < 200; j++ )`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting for every copy

```c
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) // for every item in the first half
    for (j = 100; j < 201; j++)  // into every cell
        ptr [j] = ptr[i];
```

shoud be

```c
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        ptr [i+100] = ptr[i];
```

and issue 2:

you didn't raallocate enough memory : change `realloc(ptr, 200)` to `realloc(ptr, 200 * sizeof(double))`

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working now, but I dont get it why I am overwriting it.

Comment: you were confused by the loops they are not synchronized but nested so for every step of i, j was doing the whole range of 100 to 199